# ecto installation fails on 'git submodule update'

Tags: ros, ecto

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

A few months ago I was able to install ecto on an Ubuntu 10.04 machine.  Now I'm trying again on a new machine (Ubuntu 11.04) using the [instructions found here](http://ecto.willowgarage.com/releases/amoeba-beta4/README.html).  The first three steps go OK, but then I get the following error when running 'git submodule update':

```
patrick@patrick-OptiPlex-745:~/Eclipse/ros/ecto_kitchen$ git submodule update
Cloning into catkin...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Clone of 'git@github.com:willowgarage/catkin.git' into submodule path 'catkin' failed
```

Any thoughts on how I can proceed?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28446/ecto-installation-fails-on-%27git-submodule-update%27/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are checking out over ssh.  To do that you'll need to upload your public key to github.  The other solution is to change the submodule to use the https url.  For development convenience the submodules were likely setup with ssh to make pushing easier.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-02-25**:
@tfoote - Thanks Tully! That was it exactly.  Uploading my public key to github fixed it.